# $geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm writing an aggregation query that try to match users in a certain area. I followed the [3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) version documentation (my version of `mongodb`)

```
db.collection('users').aggregate([
      {$match: {
        location: {
          $geoNear: {
            near: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [lng, lat]},
            maxDistance: globalConf.maxDistance * 1000
          }
        }
      }})
```

if I use this match in a `find` context it works . How to modify the query to make it works in an aggregate context?

The error I get is `$geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context`

Comment: [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) is aggregation pipeline stage not an aggregation  operator. So remove `$match` and use it at top level.

Comment: where do I put the `location` field (the one in the `users` collection)?

Comment: Which `location` field? [geospatial index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/geospatial-indexes/) will do the job for you.

Answer (score 4):

`$geoNear` must be in aggregation pipeline stage. And I must include `{spherical: true}` as my `location` field is a `2dsphere` type

So, the result would be

```
 db.collection('users').aggregate([
    $geoNear: {
      includeLocs: "location",
      distanceField: "distance",
      near: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [lng, lat]},
      maxDistance: globalConf.maxDistance * 1000,
      spherical: true
    }
])
```

Comment: I dont think so that will work because you did not add stage to the aggregation pipeline